# What happened to the male Leviathan?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, rashi, parashat-bereishit, genesis-bereishith

According to tradition (see [Rashi to bereishis 1:21](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165/showrashi/true#v21)), Hashem created a male and female Leviathan, but then He killed the female and salted it for the righteous. What happened to the male? Did it die sometime? When?

Comment: It's still around. The Medresh Rabbah says HaShem killed it either to save it for the right ones in o'hab, or so that they don't copulate and make more levyasons and destroy the world! So L'maseah the levyason dude is floating somewhere, while his dudet is elsewhere.... think about it, she's there for the righteous, she must be hugggge, or she died so they won't coupulate, so why was she created - for the righteous?

Comment: @FalseMessiah If you make this as a sourced answer, i'll certainly upvote that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am providing a source for the answer but one will need further research to better understand it.

Gemorah avodah zara 3b states that "[He (the Almighty) sits and makes sport with the leviathan](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.3b.8?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)"

So at least we know that the male leviathan is not dead as opposed to his female counterpart.